# Some fishy users in linux Rackspace instance, Can I disable the built in system users?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, users

I just brought up an Ubunt 12.04 instance on rackspace and I have some users that I am wondering about:

I see a couple of users on ubuntu 12.04 server which I don't seem like they need shell access: games, man, lp, news, irc.

Is shell access necessary for these users/services? Can I disable them.  I'm just paranoid because one of my servers was hacked and I just want to make sure everything is clean this time around.

Thank You,

Comment: Do they have a valid shell ? If they have a bogus shell like /bin/false, they don't have "shell access" in a meaningful sense.

Comment: @b0fh they have `/bin/sh/` does that fall in the bogus category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are standard non-privileged users/groups created by packages so their programs can run without root privileges.

If this is the only reason you suspect that your system has a security problem, then it is likely that you don't.

Additionally, it is generally a Bad Idea (TM) to just start disabling things unless you really know what you are doing. The defaults are default for a reason.